# How do I load the Codesys control for Pfc100 package?

Tags: codesys

I am using `Codesys` v3. Sp14 patch. When I update `PCF100` with `V3.5.14.20`. My 750-8100 firmware version is 11. I get an error Expected exit value of command failed: expected 0, received -1. I also get

> Error output:ipkg *** couldn't kill old gunzip process *** aborting.

When I also tried with `wago` firmware version 12,11 and 9 via wago web browser, it also gives the same error.

Comment: remove repetitive passage

Comment: This is what I hate about WAGO. As soon as you go raw Codesys you lose support and support of many libraries. Why would they do this to people who purchase their expensive PLCs and just want to save a little on software?

Comment: I got it working. The method of loading the pkg, it don't fully loaded it in there.  I used the SD card, load the file in there and going through SSH, (Linux OS), I did the ipkg install command. Depending on the version of firmware, the newer version command is opkg install.